# error in php don't know what I am doing wrong

Tags: php

I am getting this error
Warning: fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\fileFormProcess.php on line 19

Warning: feof(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\wamp\www\fileFormProcess.php on line 29

Warning: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\wamp\www\fileFormProcess.php on line 30

Warning: Wrong parameter count for explode() in C:\wamp\www\fileFormProcess.php on line 31

I been looking over the files and can not see what I am doing wrong.
here's my code:

```
<?php

if($_POST['firstName']==""|| $_POST['lastName']==""|| $_POST['address']==""||      $_POST['city']==""|| $_POST['state']==""|| $_POST['zip']==""){
header("Location:fileInsert.php?status=2");
 }
else{
$newRecord="\n";
$newRecord.=$_POST['lastName']."|".$_POST['firstName']."|".$_POST['address']."|".$_POST['city']."|".$_POST['state']."|".$_POST['zip'];

$myFile="records.txt";
$fp = fopen($myFile, "a");

//Write the data to the file
fwrite($fp, $newRecord);

//Close the file
fclose($fp);
if (file_exists($myFile)) {
$file = fopen($myFile.'r');
$rowcount=0;
echo "<html>\n";
echo " <head>\n";
echo " <title>Sucess!</title>\n";
echo " <link href=\"contact1.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\'stlesheet\">";
echo " </head>\n";
echo " <body>";
echo " <table width=\"75%\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"2\" border=\"1\">\n";
echo " <tr>\n";
while (!feof($file)) {
$line = fgets($file);
$aryData=explode("|",$line);
$firstname=$aryData[1];
$lastname=$aryData[0];
$address=$aryData[2];
$city=$aryData[3];
$state=$aryData[4];
$zip=$aryData[5];
echo "<td align=\"center\">";
echo $firstname."".lastname;
echo "<br>".$address;
echo "<br>".$city.".".$state."".$zip;
echo "</td>\n";
$rowcount++;
if ($rowcount!=0 && $rowcount%3==0){
  echo " </tr>\n";
  echo " <tr>\n";
    }

}
while($rowcount%3!=0){
 echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
 $rowcount++;
 }
 echo "</table>\n";
 }
}
echo "</body>\n";
echo " </html>\n";
```

and

```
<?php
if ($_GET['status']==2){
    $strMessage="<strong>All fields are required!</strong>";
 }
 elseif($_GET['status']==1){
     $strMessage="<strong>Your information has been added.</strong>";
}
else{
$strMessage="";
}
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link href="contact1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Write to a file</title>
 <style type="text/css">
fieldset{
width:50%;

 }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<?php echo $strMessage; ?>
<p>
<form name='myForm' method='post' action="fileFormProcess.php">
  <fildset><legand><i>All Fields are Required</i></legand>

  <table id='form'  border='0' cellpadding='6'>
  <tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='firstName'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='lastName'></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
<td>Street Address:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='address'></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
<td>City:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='city'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>State:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='state'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Zip:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='zip'></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
<td><input type='reset' value='Reset Form' name='reset'></td>
<td><input type='submit' value='Submit Form' name='submit'></td>
</tr>
  </table>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
  </p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and this is the record.txt file that it is suppose to pull from

```
  Scott|Michael|23 Guist Rd|Scranton|PA|12345
  Beesly|Pam|4359 Justin Ave|Pittsburg|PA|44709
  Halpert|Jim|450 Sawdust Lane|Chicago|IL|55830
  Braff|Zach|33082 Buckthorn Rd|Dalton|OH|40988
  Keenan|Maynard|89 Treeview Blvd|Page Springs|AZ|85377
  Hedburg|Mitch|9000 Beerbohm Dr|Cadiz|OH|43990
  Cook|Dane|23 River Rd|Krabill|OR|66264
  Griffin|Lois|123 Our Street|Quahog|RI|48756
```

Now i did save the record.txt under my www wamp file i just don't know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `$file = fopen($myFile.'r');` should be `$file = fopen($myFile,'r');`.

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting this error `Warning: fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\fileFormProcess.php on line 19`

Well, what's on line 19?

```
$file = fopen($myFile.'r');
```

It says it expects two parameters, but is only getting one. Parameters are separated by commas, but there's no commas in this line, so you're only giving it one parameter. Presumably, you meant to type `,` but typoed `.`, causing the error. Replacing the line with

```
$file = fopen($myFile,'r');
```

is all you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
$myFile.'r'
```

typo ... should be a comma, I guess ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
fopen($myFile.'r')
```

should be this:

```
fopen($myFile, 'r')
```